# Div background transparent

Tags: css, html, opacity

I have to make shadow-effect for my some block. I got transparent image width gradient from dark to transparent and use it in another div (width=100; repeat-x). But there are another elements under this shadow and they aren't shown, I see just white area at that place. How can I get transparent part of background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to see more content. What's your ‘transparent’ image? It needs to be a PNG to preserve the transparency. This should just work on all browsers except IE6, which doesn't directly support semi-transparent images.

You can work around it using an IE6-specific `AlphaImageLoader` (or one of the many PNG fix scripts that automatically set up `AlphaImageLoader` for each PNG on the page when running on IE6). However this workaround cannot tile (`repeat-x`), so you would need to make a bigger background image.